# awk: match pattern that contain only forward slash

Tags: command-line, awk

For example, if i run `df -h`

```
Filesystem                  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                        985M     0  985M   0% /dev
tmpfs                       201M  9.1M  192M   5% /run
/dev/sdb3                    87G   26G   57G  31% /
tmpfs                      1003M   15M  989M   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs                       5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                      1003M     0 1003M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
```

From its output if i want to print a line

```
/dev/sdb3                    87G   26G   57G  31% /
```

that contain root partition `/`.

Then How to do it with awk?

I do not want to use `/dev/sdb3` in search pattern. In search pattern, use only `/`.
I've tried [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19789643/search-pattern-containing-forward-slash-using-awk) posted on Stackoverflow but it did not work.

Comment: Horribly inefficient way to do this. Just use `df`: `df -h /`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use plain `df`:

```
df -h /
```

However, in awk, since this is the last field, just compare directly:

```
$ df -h | awk '$NF == "/"'
/dev/sda1        18G  7.7G  9.0G  47% /
```